# I'm stuck with this logic proble.m

Tags: php, mysql, logic

**WHAT I HAVE:**

-I have a file with various products ( Flag "P" mean reserved, without "P" mean sold but not reserved)

**ELEMENTS**

```
        PRODOTTO                      Quantita    Terminale     
    TAMOXIFENE EG*20CPR RIV 20MG      00002n        04 
    FERRITIN COMPLEX*OS 10FL 8ML      00001     P   01  
    VOLTADOL*10CER MEDIC 140MG        00001n        05   
    LEDERFOLIN*10CPR 7,5MG            00002     P   03
```

-From this file,through a regular php expression (that search only strings with "P" flag), I extract products and insert it into mysql db.

insericineldb.php

```
$txt = file_get_contents('./FILE', true);
$specialChars = preg_quote( '#$%^&*()+=-[]\';,./{}|\":<>?~', '#' );

preg_match_all('#([0-9]{4,9}\s+[A-Z]{1}\s+([' . $specialChars . 'A-Z0-9 ]+)\s+([0-9]{3,7})n?\s+P\s+([0-9]+))#', $txt, $match); 

    $products = [];
    foreach (array_keys($match[2]) as $idx) {
        $tagliaprodotto = rtrim(substr($match[2][$idx],1));
        $tagliaquantita = ltrim($match[3][$idx],'0');
        $products[] = [
            'prodotto'  => $tagliaprodotto,
            'quantita' => $tagliaquantita,
            'terminale'   => $match[4][$idx]
        ];
    }

     $query = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO tabella (prodotto, quantita, terminale, data) VALUES (:prodotto, :quantita, :terminale, NOW()) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantita = VALUES(quantita), terminale = VALUES(terminale)');

    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $query->execute($product);
    }
```

-I extract products automatically thanks to the use of a batch (which monitors the variation of the file).

**BATCH**

```
@echo off
:loop  
timeout -t 1 >nul  
for %%i in (c:\file) do echo %%~ai|find "a">nul || goto :loop
"c:\xampp\php\php.exe" -f c:\xampp\htdocs\inseriscineldb.php
rem do workload
attrib -a c:\file
goto :loop
```

---

The file:

-At a certain time NOT REGULAR (when they make the final order, 2 times a day) is emptied NOT COMPLETELY (some strings **with and without "P"** remain in the file but they aren't important, are important only for logic because I can't use an if as: when P=0 don't start the query).

-Furthermore sometimes some products (ES. FERRITIN COMPLEX*OS 10FL 8ML  00001 P 01) is eliminated **VOLUNTARILY** (Suppose a customer wants a 50-milliliter product, i reserve it but after he wants a 8-milliliter product, the old 50 milliliters order will not be deleted from the database)

**PROBLEM:**

1)So if I enter products into the database through INSERT INTO when one of the elements is removed **voluntarily**, it isn't removed from the database.

2)However, if I use REPLACE instead of INSERT, when the file is emptied, the other elements inside the database will also be deleted and now I'm stuck.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155707/discussion-on-question-by-squalo-im-stuck-with-this-logic-proble-m). If you are asked for additional information, you need to [edit] it into your question. While you're editing, you should also change your title so it *describes what you're trying to do*, rather than just saying you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

A way to to this in a pretty simple manner, is to read all the **elements** from the Database ( with a "select * from tabella) then check which one is present into the file and delete / insert / update what you need.

Comment: Yes but how? I cannot find any solution. The query is launched each time the file undergoes a change.

Comment: when the file get's modified, you should execute: select * from tabella. Then, loop through the record that the query returns. I imagine that "prodotto" is one for each "element", so you can check if in the file is "prodotto" present. If not, remove the row from the database. If it's present, execute your query.

Comment: This is impossible to do ... because at a certain time the products will disappear and in this way they will be deleted from the database